# Select chat messages unread by current user id in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, chat

I have a chat app. User can have many chats. Chats can have many users. Chats have messages. Messages have readers.

Simplified database structure:

```sql
# users
id

# chats
id

# chat_messages
id
chat_id (fk chats.id)
author_id (fk users.id)
message

# chat_message_readers
id
message_id (fk chat_messages.id)
user_id (fk users.id)
```

I'm trying to get list of messages which were not read by user (messages which don't have reader with user id). My attempts:

List of messages with readers:

```sql
select cm.id, count(cmr.id) as readers
from chat_messages as cm
left join chat_message_readers as cmr
on cm.id = cmr.message_id
group by cm.id
```

List of messages with no readers:

```sql
select cm.id, count(cmr.id) as readers
from chat_messages as cm
left join chat_message_readers as cmr
on cm.id = cmr.message_id
where cmr.user_id is null
group by cm.id
```

I'm stuck at combining above with current user id. Should select all messages except messages which were read by current user (e.g. `chat_message_readers.user_id != 1`). Would love some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `left join` version:

```
select cm.id, (cmr.user_id is not null) as has_been_read_by_user
from chat_messages cm left join
     chat_message_readers cmr
     on cm.id = cmr.message_id and cmr.user_id = ?
where cmr.user_id is null;
```

Aggregation is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I do miss understanding and knowledge on using `and` in joins. Thanks, this worked. I've added aggregation because the whole plan is to select chats list for user with unread messages count. I've used your solution and seems like the data is correct (user id - 1, chat ids - 1,2):

```sql
select c.id, count(cm.id) as unread_messages
from chats c
left join chat_messages cm
on cm.chat_id = c.id
left join chat_message_readers as cmr
on cm.id = cmr.message_id and cmr.user_id = 1
where cmr.user_id is null
and c.id in (1, 2)
group by c.id
```

Good enough?

Comment: @Vlad . . . That's fine, but you only get one row per user rather than each unread message.

Comment: yes, I'm using `count` to get amount of unread messages, to show inside a bubble next to chat title. Thank you for help ♥️

Comment: Hey. I've found a bug in my query from reply. If chat doesn't have any messages or chat has read and unread messages, unread count works. However, if chat has messages and all of them are read, this chat is absent from select result. Maybe you can suggest the reason or resolution? Thanks

Comment: @Vlad . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question.